# MPMoviePlayerController failed to play video from remote url

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

If I hit below url in browser, it plays video but my below code is not playing it on iPhone.

http://ec2-107-21-15-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/static/uploads/1337/photos/5819/38111.mp4

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ec2-107-21-15-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/static/uploads/1337/photos/5819/38111.mp4"]];

moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

this is the screenshot of the iPhone.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated. You can use AVPlayer instead.

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:"URL"];
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
controller.player = player;
[player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the `MPMoviePlayerController` that it needs to stream the video. Just add the following line:

`moviePlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;`

Answer (score 0):

**yes , you have to tell its streaming url as :**

```
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
```

then prepare to play

```
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```